# What is the life time of object passed as receiver for a QAction in a QMenu widget?

Tags: qt

I'm working on QMenu to implement some custom functionality.
I'm having trouble in understanding when does a particular object gets destroyed during the execution of QMenu pop and triggering of any action.
here is the snippet of the actual codde :

myCustomMenu, a derived class from QMenu has a function customExec()

```
void myCustomMenu::customExec()
{    myCustomMenu *rearrangedMenu = new myCustomMenu();
     myCustomFunctionalityClass *mCFC = new mCFS(this, rearrangedMenu);
     //This class saves "this" as originalMenu i.e. the current menu object's address in      a variable so that I can access with following action's SLOT.
     rearrangedMenu->addAction(" Open My Custom Widget", mCFC, SLOT(showWidget()) ;
     rearrangedMenu->exec();
}
```

When I click on "Open My Custom Widget" a gui widget opens up, and inside the showWidget() if I try to access mCFC->originalMenu->size() it crashes. 
It appears that the object has been destroyed. 
My problem is that how can I access that object? And if it gets destroyed then why not mCFC object which is also a local variable.

EDIT: showWidget slot is a member of mCFC class.

Please add comments if you have any doubt understanding it. I'm stuck on this since a while.

Comment: What is `mCFC->originalMenu`? How do you access mCFC from your slot?